How to apply updates to a Monaco editor/model and get autoclosing brackets
Trying to figure out a way to hook into Monaco bracket/quotation autoclosing behavior programmatically. Basically instead of a user typing the characters const c = ( -> editor completes const c = (), use some Monaco editor API to achieve the same result, possibly by something along the lines of
const myEditor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: `const c = `,
    language: "javascript",
    automaticLayout: true,
    autoClosingBrackets: "always",
});

myEditor.getModel().applyEdits([
  {
    text: '(', // Trying to trigger the autoclose operation
    range: { ... }
  }
]);

With the above code however, the resulting text in the editor window is just const c = ( without the closed parentheses. What Monaco API should I use to simulate a keystroke '(' to trigger the autoclose?
